# Does Git require a centralized server or not?

Tags: git

I'm confused about Git. I get that it's *distributed* in the sense that each developer has their own repository.

But my confusion comes when the developers *sync* their repositories. There *has* to be a centralized repository, right?

Comment: No. You need to somehow be able to access each other's repo, but that doesn't necessarily mean there has to be a centralized one. Others could be accessing your machine directly.

Comment: Most people choose to use git mostly with a centralized system (e.g. github), but git itself does not specify or restrict this.

Comment: Related question on [softwareengineering.se]: http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/315252/220461

Comment: Each developer has a full repository.  It is the way you choose to synchronize the repositories that determine if you have a central repository and if so, which one it is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. You can very much have N developers in your team, and sync between each other, pushing and pulling code from their respective repositories.

The "central" repo has technically no more significance than any other repo in the system.

However, having a single canonical repo that's considered "the main" or "the central" makes organizing that much easier, you know where to pull builds from, and what to run your tests against. So nearly all of the projects I've seen using Git use that paradigm.

Answer (score 2):

A centralized server is not required but it simplifies the collaboration a lot. It also serves as the authoritative source for the master branch.

In the absence of a centralized server, every time a new developer joins the project all the existing developers need to be notified, in order to make the "distributed" part work as expected.

Sure, a different topology can be used but in the end the centralized server topology will probably be reached because it provides the simplest way to publish your code and stay up-to-date with the changes published by the co-workers.